# Enable HTTPS in Sonarqube with keystore

Tags: https, sonarqube, keystore, jks

i need to enable https into sonarqube. I already have a keystore (JKS File), but i don't know how do this operation.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a reverse proxy with proper TLS configuration.

Here are some information :
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Securing+the+Server+Behind+a+Proxy

Comment: thanks, but with only this I can not do it You can give me more information?for example: where can i set "X_FORWARDED_PROTO: https"?

Comment: All that configuration is dependent of your http server. Which one are you using ?